# Python: Combination output in multiple excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter, python-3.8

I am new in Python. I have generated a 3 number combination set out of 24 numbers (Total combinations 2024). My intention is to put the combinations in different excel sheets in the same workbook. For example, 100 combinations in each sheet. I got some reference from this site and tried to use it. But, still all the combinations are generating in the same sheet.

```
import xlsxwriter


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()


import itertools as it
combin = it.combinations(range(1,25),3)
count_combin = []
for i in combin:
    count_combin.append(i)



max_row = 100
row_num = 0

for data in count_combin:

    if row_num == max_row:
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        row_num = 0

for row, group in enumerate(count_combin):
    for col in range(3):
        worksheet.write (row, col, group[col])
        row_num += 1

workbook.close()
```

**Please enlighten me what's wrong in the coding?**

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (explanation in code comments)

```
import xlsxwriter
import itertools as it
from math import floor

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
combin = it.combinations(range(1,25),3)

max_row = 100
lst_combin = list(combin)

for x, c in enumerate(lst_combin):
    # if x is zero or reachs max_row add a new work sheet
    if x % max_row == 0:
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    # nx = x unless x is greater than max row ..
    # .. then nx = x  - max rows multiplied by the number of max rows in x
    nx = x
    if x > max_row:
        nx = x - max_row*(floor(x/max_row))

    worksheet.write(nx, 0, c[0])
    worksheet.write(nx, 1, c[1])
    worksheet.write(nx, 2, c[2])

    workbook.close()
```